# Multiple select cases in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, select-case

I have tried the below:

```
Select Case Combo1.SelectedItem Or Combo2.SelectedItem
```

But I get the error:

```
Conversion from String "string here" to type 'Long' is not valid
```

Is it possible to have multiple select cases?

Comment: .SelectedItem is not a boolean

Comment: By using `Or`, you will compare the both values on a binary level (adding bit by bit). So vb.net will try to convert the string to a type that can be compared on a binary level. The implicit convertion of vb.net will thus try to convert any type to `Long` for the binary comparition. But there is no implicit converter for `String` to `Long`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You separate multiple values by using a comma:

```
Case Combo1.SelectedItem, Combo2.SelectedItem
```

Using `Or` would make it an expression that would be evaluated before compared to the value in the `Select`.

If your value in the `Select` is a `Long` value, then you may need to convert the strings from the controls:

```
Case CLng(Combo1.SelectedItem), CLng(Combo2.SelectedItem)
```

To address the question directly, using multiple values as a test expression in a select is not possible:

```
Select Case v1, v2 'Not possible
```

Comment: Dim test As String

        Select Case Combo1.SelectedItem,combo2.SelectedItem

            Case "1"
                test= "ND1"
            Case "2"
                test= "D1"
            Case "3"
                test= "ND2"
            Case Else
                Return Nothing
        End Select

        Return test

Comment: @user1295053: Aha, you are trying to use multiple values as the test expresion, not in a case. Sorry for the confusion. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Googled and saw this question without an answer. Upon further research, I found this to work for my purposes.

Basically, you start with:

Select case True

Then each case statement can be combinations of the two variables. When both are met, the case is true and will execute the appropriate code.

https://forums.asp.net/t/611892.aspx?To+do+a+select+case+using+two+variables+or+parameters

Answer (score -3):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim value As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 5
            value = (GetCode(i, j))
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "i=" & i & "->j=" & j & "=" & value & vbCrLf
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Function GetCode(ByVal v1 As Integer, ByVal v2 As Integer) As Integer
    Dim retval As Integer
    Dim forselect As String
    forselect = v1 & v2
    Select Case forselect
        Case 11
            retval = 11
        Case 12
            retval = 12
        Case 13
            retval = 13
        Case 14
            retval = 14
        Case 15
            retval = 15
        Case 21
            retval = 21
        Case 22
            retval = 22
        Case 23
            retval = 23
        Case 24
            retval = 24
        Case 25
            retval = 25
        Case 31
            retval = 31
        Case 32
            retval = 32
        Case 3, 3
            retval = 33
        Case 34
            retval = 34
        Case 35
            retval = 35


    End Select

    Return retval
End Function
```